# return token string from filter to controller angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to return a token string from  filter to  my controller

```
    app. factory('PushNotification', function($rootScope,$q) {
    var Service = {};
    Service.getTokenKey = getTokenKey;
   const messaging = firebase.messaging();
   function getTokenKey(){
   messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken();

  }).then(function (token) {

    console.log('NOTIFICATION TOKEN ', token);
    $rootScope.token = token;
   })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  });
   return Service;})
```

Controller Code:

```
 Notificationservice.getTokenKey().then(function(response){
   $scope.token = response )}
```

Got Error saying that .then is defined and also response is undefined. finally added to $rootScope, now how do i return that token value to my  controller??

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

  app. factory('PushNotification', function($rootScope,$q) {
    var Service = {};
    Service.getTokenKey = getTokenKey;

   const messaging = firebase.messaging();
   function getTokenKey(){
   messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    messaging.getToken().then(function (token) {

    console.log('NOTIFICATION TOKEN ', token);
   // $rootScope.token = token;
    return token; // try this
   })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  });
   return Service;})


if this is not working, please provide clear description or plunker, so that we can work it out.
```